# I get didreceivememorywarning uitableview usuing AFNetworking to download the images?

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

Hello everyone I have a `UITableView` which I use `AfNetworking` to load very large images. But however when the `didreceivememorywarning` is hit my app just crashes. Here is my code :

In `AFNetworking+uiimageview.m` I have added this as suggested :

```
@implementation AFImageCache

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(didReceiveMemoryWarning)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    DebugLog(@"AFNetworking DID RECEIVED MEMORY WARNING ");
    [self removeAllObjects];
}
```

And my code in uitableview is  as follows :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        TousCell *tvCell;
        NSArray *nib;
        nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TousCell" owner:self options:nil];
        tvCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        tvCell.lbltitle.text=[[dict valueForKey:@"message"]objectAtIndex:i];

[tvCell.imgPhoto setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/%@", [[dict valueForKey:@"photo"]objectAtIndex:i]]]];
```

May be I am recreating the `cells` each and everytime? But I am sure its linked to the images download as the images are v large sometimes ( in size about 2 - 3 Mb?).

Comment: it's a bad idea  to request an image from a remote source each time when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, write a method were you get images for current visible rows and save them to an array. Using this array you could get a reference to downloaded image: [tvCell.imgPhoto setImage:[arrayWithImages objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recreating the table cell each time so if images are different they will take a lot of space. You must reuse table view cells as much as possible using the

```
[tableView dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:]
```

method and registering your nib in the view controller view did load using the:

```
[tableView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:]
```

method.

Also note that if the images are large, AFNetworking offers you the possibility to downsize them before returning to the caller. This is especially useful if you need to fit a large image on a small cell (e.g. the one from a table view). Note that AFNetworking doesn't provide the resizing functions but returns the image in two different blocks: one before post-processing and one after post-processing.

Comment: Hello there thanks for your replay but can you give me an example of how should i modify the code above to achieve this? And also how to use AFNetworking to downsize the images?

Comment: i have edited this

        TousCell *tvCell = (TousCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        NSArray *nib;
if(tvcell==nil){
  nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TousCell" owner:self options:nil];
        tvCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

Comment: Finally what I did its to write a php script where it will downscale the images. It works since the images are small thumbs now. [tvCell.imgPhoto setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/RESIZE-IMAGE.php?image=%@", [[dict valueForKey:@"photo"]objectAtIndex:i]]]];

Comment: Of course resizing the image at server side is better, especially if you support caching.

Answer (score 1):

2 or 3 MB is way too large for a thumbnail picture in a UITableViewCell. And you are re - creating a cell each time. You should use

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

to improve performance